# java apriori implementation L2 from C2

Tags: java, apriori

I would like to store the function output (that is saved in a txt file) to generate L2 in apriori algorithm. I am not able to copy the values to any kind of datastructs. Where am I going wrong, I want to reuse this output in someother class. I tried to store in Arraylist, list etc but when I print I see junk values. Please clarify this.

```
print(combination,list1,list2);

public void print(int[] combination, ArrayList<String> list1, ArrayList<String> list2) 

{

    String[] listArr2 = new String[list2.size()];
      list2.toArray(listArr2);

      Arrays.sort(listArr2, new Comparator<String>() {

          public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
              return Integer.valueOf(s1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(s2));
          }
      }); 


      ArrayList<String> list5 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < combLength;i++){

        System.out.print(listArr2[combination[i]] + " ");// <---- how to save this return as copy to another class
        list5 = Arrays.asList(listArr2[combination[i]] + " ");

    }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println( list5);

}
```